# Isn't it better to reserve wasted bounty for next bounty assigning?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, bounty

We have two methodologies for prizing a bounty:

1. Prizing by Bounty Owner assignment.
2. Prizing by system assignment to which answer post with most upvotes (more than 2).

Now, assume we have a question, that has a bounty but none of the answers are useful and acceptable by Bounty Owner, also none of them have score upvote more than 2. So it will be wasted after 7 days.

**My Idea**: For these kinds of situations we can reserve it for the next bounty assignment. Then we can sum the reserved bounty and the new bounty to get more attention.

Comment: You mean, added to the next bounty on the same question? That this reputation is “lost” is not really a big deal on any case.

Comment: Makes sense, I think it would be better than what we currently have.

Comment: @oguzismail, You know what I'm saying. the wasted reputation is not important at all. but we should think. the question was important the some user assigned bounty to it. when it didn't get enough attention, neither BO nor System prize it, So why we should waste it?! We must reserve it for next bounty assignment. to collect more attention. because it was a big problem for that user the BO.

Comment: Yeah I mostly agree with that. But if bounties pile up a lot, like 10000 points, that'd give the next bounty owner too much power.

Comment: @oguzismail, evet aynen, What's the issue? man, finding true answer is the main problem, I think the next Bounty Owners won't give power, the Question just will give more and more attention. just it.

Comment: Are lottery awards piled up when there are no winners? Repeatedly posting bounties already gives more attention. The bounty you "pay" is like an advertisement. You pay up-front and might not get what you wanted. If you put another bounty and get a good answer it should receive that bounty. There is no reason for it to receive a previous bounty that already ended

Comment: Many lotteries do indeed pile up prizes when there are no winners. But that does not make this a better or worse idea.

Comment: In a way, that is *almost* the [existing situation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty): *"if you offer multiple bounties on the same question, __the minimum spend doubles with each subsequent bounty__ (50 reputation on the first bounty, 100 reputation on the second, 200 on the third, and so on).*"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First of all, the bounty was **not wasted**. Bounties **pay for advertisement**, they draw *attention*. There is never a guarantee that placing a bounty will produce a helpful answer!

If there was no good enough answer then either the *question* hasn’t done a good enough job of framing the problem or the problem is too hard to be solved on Stack Overflow. That’s not the fault of the bounty system.

Next, why should other questions with bounties be penalised for the lack of suitable answers? If we carried an unawarded bounty forward then you get to place a bigger bounty on the same question, than others can place on other questions. Why should a post that *already failed to get good answers* be allowed to attract attention at a reduced cost? **Carrying forward unawarded bounties is unfair to other questions with bounties**.

So no, we should absolutely not carry unawarded bounties over to a next bounty being placed.

Answer (score 7):

This would potentially disincentivize people from quickly answering questions with bounties. If it looks like a question with a bounty of 100 points might get an additional bounty if it goes unanswered (maybe it has a high score and lots of bookmarks, maybe even some "I'm having the same problem" type comments), why not wait until it's gotten 2+ bounties and get a lot more points?

It'd be rewarding people for *not* answering the question during the previous bounty periods.

Comment: I don't believe your assumption,  peoples are greedy to earn bounty, so you cannot assume everybody leave the bounty to a future that maybe never come. maybe after this bounty no one assign another bounty. your assumption is completely wrong.